# JS Set vs Array for storing functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, set

Is it better to store js functions in Set or Array?
How I understand, set is binary Tree. And storing in set there must be compare function.

By "better", I mean read and write performance, search and delete, and finally for loop for all entries. I will call these functions in each frame. So It is very important to save time.

About memory, I don't care so much, because functions are not many, over 100-500 functions per array, and 5-10 array. Overall 1000-5000 functions.

I know that set is better for adding and removing, and array is better for iterating over elements. But I cant understand how it will work for functions.

Comment: As per the docs: "The Set object lets you store **unique** values of any type, whether primitive values or object references"

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "better"?

Comment: Ok I know. I will store unique functions. 
I just want to know which one is better for functions.
I know that for numbers or strings it is better to store on set when you will search and remove.

Comment: At the end of the day, it doesn't really matter, unless you are worried about duplicates, intersections, unions, or differences between two sets, which doesn't make much sense with functions.

Comment: ok @Soviut I will update

Answer (score 0):

In all cases of performance, you should profile both since the performance metrics can change from year to year. You're probably not going to even notice any measurable performance differences until you get into the hundreds of thousands of items.

Based on the specs you defined in your question, the simple answer is, it doesn't matter. Functions are first-class citizens in Javascript so there is no differences between how an array or set works for data and how it works for functions.

You're not going to run into any performance issues iterating over a few thousand functions every frame; This is core javascript functionality and highly optimized already. The place where you'll need to optimize is the functions themselves since the more complex they are, the longer each one will take to run.

Rather than worry about it now, just use an array, build your project and see if you even hit any performance bottlenecks. Then you can profile your code to see where those bottlenecks are happening. They most likely will not be due to the array manipulation but the code run in the functions themselves.

Comment: @Gor I've updated my answer to reflect your question. Short answer, just use an array since this isn't going to be your performance bottleneck.